# The search engine adds to much importance to "how to prevent"?

Tags: discussion, search, search-engine

The search engine treats general phrase like "how to prevent" as more important part than the actual part of the question, so I'm getting this list of totally unrelated search results:

```
2 How to prevent Windows 10 from clobbering GRUB?
0 How to prevent a directory from being edited 1
1 How to prevent Windows partition to access(read) Linux partition files? 2
11 How to prevent fork bomb? 2
1 How to prevent kernel modules to load? [closed] 2
3 How to prevent script from deleting itself 3
```

Is it that hard to make a search engine to ignore general phrases  (easily deductible by repeatability) so the search would return any useful result?

Comment: So, what was the actual text you had entered? Seems useful and relevant to share.

Comment: SO’s search is unusable. Just use’s google’s search applied to SO: `site:stackoverflow.com how to prevent unicorns from stealing my waffles`.

Comment: Adding insult to injury, when you want to mark something as a duplicate of something else, it seems SO simply suggests the most popular questions for that tag, instead of those which contain similar terms to the one you want to close. (Finding duplicates via SO's internal search is also next to impossible, so I suppose that's why they don't even try.)

Comment: Maybe it is me or it has become custom by now but I find your wording unnecessary grieving for the SE developers  that work on this feature. Why is that needed?

Comment: The only thing I use the SE search for is for filtering by tag - which it seems to do well. For general searches, though, even if I _know_ the answer is on SE, I'll go to Google/Bing/DuckDuckGo ("Bingleduck"?).

Comment: To close voters: can you please explain why this question is unclear?

Comment: I don't understand why someone would cripple perfectly valid question by transforming it to the statement. Had it done to make original poster to look stupid?

Comment: > So, what was the actual text you had entered? Seems useful and relevant to share.
>
>
No, it's absolutely irrelevant here. You can easily reproduce the behavior just by typing anything alike.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done any serious text search / natural language processing myself but I suspect the answer to the following question:

> Is it that hard to make a search engine to ignore general phrases (easily deductible by repeatability) so the search would return any useful result?

Would be yes, for example if the algorithm determined "SQL query" was repeated many times and ignored it a search for "SQL query sum rows" might start returning questions related to Excel, R etc. Where I find the on-site search useful is by removing some of the fluff and combine it with a tag to end up with a query such as:

```
[c] prevent scanf buffer overflow
```

Then you start to get some more focused results. Alternatively as a comment suggests dedicated search engines tend to have more sophisticated search strategies and when I did a DuckDuckGo on the following it came up with exactly the same question:

```
site:stackoverflow.com prevent scanf buffer overflow
```

Comment: > Would be yes, for example if the algorithm determined "SQL query" was repeated many times and ignored it a search for "SQL query sum rows" might start returning questions related to Excel, R etc.
>
>
>

You need one more step to bypass this. Just compare phrase you're going to ignore with a tag list. Obviously, "sql" and "query" are tags and won't be excluded. And if you want to have a "sophisticated" search engine, you need to assign calculated weights to terms rather just exclude them. So words like "how" would have less weight than "SQL" , for example. It's not that hard to achieve.

Comment: > Alternatively as a comment suggests dedicated search engines
>
>
>

Soooo, the advice is: Each time you're asking question, just open external site to search for duplicates rather than refer the offered list? Most of the people who ask questions, including me, won't do that. So if the number of duplicates has any concern for SO team, the search engine needs to be fixed.